# Vue Js Filter by Movie or Series Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to create a filter were when the user clicks on the Series Button only series will be shown on the website.
[screenshot project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs08R.jpg)

```
Movies:[
      {MovieName: 'La Casa de Papel',rating: 9,type:'Series', imgPath: 'lacasadePapel.png'},
      {MovieName: 'Venom (2018)',rating: 7, type:'Movie', imgPath: 'Venom.png'},
      ]
<div class="NavbarContainer">
    <button>Movies</button>
    <button @click="SerieOrMovie">Series</button>
    <button id="FavoriteBtn">Favorites ({{amountFav}})</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
  <div class="MoviesContainer">
    <div class="Movies" v-for="(movie,index) in filteredMovies" :id="index">
      <img class="image_img" :src="require('../assets/MoviesMap/' + movie.imgPath)">
      <div class="image_Overlay">
        <button @click="addedMovie">Add to Favorites</button>
        <button>Watch {{movie.MovieName}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is what i tried to do but doesnt work

```
computed:{
    SerieOrMovie(){
      return this.Movies.filter((Movies) =>{
        return Movies.type.toLowerCase().match('Series')
      })
    },
```

Comment: when i click on the <button @click="SerieOrMovie">Series</button> i want to check in the array of Movies[] if the type == 'Series' okay show only the Series/objects on the web page

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you want to accomplice.

This will give you all series:

```js
computed: {
  Series() {
    return this.Movies.filter((Movies) => Movies.type == "Series")
  }
```